# Install default database with AIR app

Tags: sqlite, air

I want to ship a default SQLite database, with some predefined key/value pairs in a table, along with an Adobe AIR application. What is the best method to accomplish this? In my mind, this would be as simple as updating an xml file and rebuilding the application. I've come across this [solution](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/communityengine/index.cfm?event=showdetails&productId=4&postId=10483) but it looks a little hackish to me (having to copy a database to another location).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible way to do it would be to write some code in the AIR app that generates the database with the initial data that should be there. This code could be executed only on first run of the program, or if the database doesn't exist.